# Correctly configure htaccess for 2 websites under 1 domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am a little confused so I could use some help.

I have a joomla installation in root, www.mydomain.com (let's call it #1)

I have a second joomla installation in a subdirectory www.mydomain.com/othersite (#2)

I need them to be separate sites but under the same domain, and using various tools to check my seo for the #2 site, they indicate both sitemap.xml and robots.txt as the ones from the root #1 site. But it has its own sitemap and robots.txt obviously.

I also want and have set in google the WWW as preferred version so i used a non-www to www redirect for both sites.

What should I put in #1 .htaccess file and what in #2 .htaccess file in order for them to be working as expected for seo and everything?

I am sure there is something wrong here, below I will show you the parts in both htaccess files:

## 1 root .htaccess for www.mydomain.com

```
IndexIgnore * Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes
##

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
# RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.my-domain\.com RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$
[NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

## 2 www.my-domain.com/othersite

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/othersite/ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.com/othersite/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /othersite

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Edit your post and format it as code.

Comment: You are right I apologize, I think the moderator did that for me and I thank him. Is my question clear though?